# Full-text search on content of complex jsonb

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search, jsonb, postgresql-9.6

I have pretty complex jsonb column with nested arrays and objects. And I need to perform full-text search on it.
Example of json:

```
{
"buyer": {
    "email": "1010001419test@ekbseo.ru",
    "person": {
        "phone": "1010001419",
        "taxId": "590202081324",
        "address": "г Москва, ул Авиаторов, д 34 ",
        "lastName": "Зайцева",
        "passport": {
            "issuer": "йцукйцук",
            "deptCode": "123241",
            "issueDate": [
                1111,
                11,
                11
            ],
            "numAndSeries": "0001212810"
        },
        "birthDate": [
            1952,
            2,
            18
        ],
        "firstName": "Зоя",
        "birthPlace": "фывфыв",
        "patronymic": "Антоновна",
        "citizenship": "Россия"
    }
},
"dealNo": "05-0000004",
"created": [
    2017,
    3,
    6
],
"services": [
    "SGR"
],
"transactId": "602032128",
"dealDetails": {
    "secondary": {
        "deposit": 200000,
        "sellers": [
            {
                "bank": {
                    "bic": "044525225",
                    "city": "Москва",
                    "name": "ПУБЛИЧНОЕ АКЦИОНЕРНОЕ ОБЩЕСТВО \"СБЕРБАНК РОССИИ\"",
                    "correspondentAccount": "30101810400000000225"
                },
                "email": "dsfs@sdf.ru",
                "amount": 4800000,
                "person": {
                    "phone": "1234132512",
                    "taxId": "590202081324",
                    "address": "г Москва, ул Марьинский Парк, д 45 стр 1 ",
                    "lastName": "Трутненко",
                    "passport": {
                        "issuer": "",
                        "deptCode": "",
                        "issueDate": [
                            -999999999,
                            1,
                            1
                        ],
                        "numAndSeries": ""
                    },
                    "birthDate": [
                        1111,
                        11,
                        11
                    ],
                    "firstName": "ываыаы",
                    "birthPlace": "фывфыв",
                    "patronymic": null,
                    "citizenship": "Россия"
                },
                "account": "48213412341234234234"
            }
        ],
        "propertyAddress": "г Москва, ул Вавилова, д 19 "
    }
},
"bankContacts": {
    "bankOfficeId": 3561,
    "mortgageManager": {
        "casId": 88928,
        "email": "sbtestmik1@yandex.ru",
        "phone": "79853622342",
        "lastName": "Дзержински",
        "firstName": "Макар",
        "patronymic": "Олегович"
    },
    "mortgageDeptHead": {
        "casId": 88923,
        "email": "sbtestrcik@yandex.ru",
        "phone": "72384798798",
        "lastName": "Михрюткин",
        "firstName": "Валентин",
        "patronymic": "Геннадьевич"
    }
},
"contractInfo": {
    "city": "Москва",
    "price": 5000000,
    "cadastralNum": "65:65:76876:876",
    "contractDate": [
        1111,
        11,
        11
    ]
},
"creditContract": {
    "number": "41221312",
    "ownCapital": 1000000,
    "loanCapital": 4000000
}
```

}

Actually I need to search in `deal_no`, `buyer.person.phone`, `buyer.person.address.**.(all text values here)`,  `dealDetails.secondary.sellers[].(all text values here)`, `bankContacts.(all text values here)`
What is the best way to perform this?

I use postgresql 9.6

Comment: Any success on it @asm0dey?

Comment: @rusllonrails look at my own answer, please

Answer (score 2):

This is how my pretty similar task looks like.

DB table looks like:

```
 CREATE TABLE sites (
   id text NOT NULL,
   doc jsonb,
   PRIMARY KEY (id)
 )
```

Data we are storing in `doc` column is a complex nested `JSONB` data:

```
   {
      "_id": "123",
      "type": "Site",
      "identification": "Custom ID",
      "title": "SITE 1",
      "address": "UK, London, Mr Tom's street, 2",
      "buildings": [
          {
               "uuid": "12312",
               "identification": "Custom ID",
               "name": "BUILDING 1",
               "deposits": [
                   {
                      "uuid": "12312",
                      "identification": "Custom ID",             
                      "audits": [
                          {
                             "uuid": "12312",         
                              "sample_id": "SAMPLE ID"                
                          }
                       ]
                   }
               ]
          } 
       ]
    }
```

So structure of my `JSONB` looks like:

```
SITE 
  -> ARRAY OF BUILDINGS
     -> ARRAY OF DEPOSITS
       -> ARRAY OF AUDITS
```

We need to implement full text search by some values in each of type of entry:

```
SITE (identification, title, address)
BUILDING (identification, name)
DEPOSIT (identification)
AUDIT (sample_id)
```

SQL query should run a full text search in these field values only.

Answer (score 1):

Best way I've found so far is following:

1. Create tsvector returning function, which works withour json like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION deal_tsvector(deal_no text, data jsonb)
  RETURNS tsvector AS $$
BEGIN
  RETURN to_tsvector('russian', deal_no || ' ' || data::text);
END
```

2. create index on it like this:

```sql
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_deal_fts ON deal USING gin(deal_tsvector(deal_no, request_json));
```

Comment: Thanks for response. I have pretty similar task, but do not have much experience with PG. Can you please also share an example how you adding custom PG function and index for nested JSONB structures (for example: Would this approach work if you need to have full text search by dealDetails.secondary.sellers.bank.bic values)

Comment: As you can see, we're just casting data to text, so tsvector will work on whole json content and of course, it won't work on single fields, but nothing can stop you from creating custom indexes for single fields of json.

Comment: hey man, thank you. Quick question: does you app where you use this stuff is private or public? Asking because would like to see full implementation of your task if possible ) Anyway thank you a lot.

Comment: @rusllonrails it's private, sorry.

Comment: ok @asm0dey np ) Maybe you can share just a full example for one of nested fields you done. For example `dealDetails.secondary.sellers.anyfiled`, how you indexed it and then how you queried it.

Comment: @rusllonrails as I've already said we've built function on the whole JSON (deal_tsvector) and then built the index (idx_deal_fts) on that function.